# How to perform Swap (via uniswap) only when requirement is true?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I am currently in the process of writing a contract for a token on the Ethereum blockchain. However, I have encountered a problem. I am trying to link a swap function for uniswap to a condition (that the maximum wallet size of 3% is not exceeded by the held balance of the token and the amount of tokens to be swapped). I have the following function for this:

```
...

_maxWltSize = (totalSupply() * 3) / 100;

...

// Swap ETH for tokens using Uniswap

function swapETHForToken(

uint256 amountOutMin,

address to,

uint256 deadline

) external payable ensure(deadline) nonReentrant {

require(msg.value > 0, "Amount must be greater than 0");

// calculate estimated token for eth equivalent

uint256 estimatedTokens = getEstimatedTokenForETH(msg.value);

// prove if max_walletsize does not passed throug swap

require(balanceOf(to) + estimatedTokens <= _maxWltSize, "Swap would exceed maximum wallet balance");

// Calculate the fees

uint256 burnFeeAmount = _calcBurningFee(msg.value);

uint256 devFeeAmount = _calcDevFee(msg.value);

// Calculate the amount to swap after deducting fees

uint amountToSwap = msg.value - burnFeeAmount - devFeeAmount;

// Prepare the token path for the swap (ETH -> weth -> Token)

address[] memory path = new address[](2);

path[0] = weth; // Use the updated weth address

path[1] = address(this);

// Perform the swap on Uniswap

uniswapRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: amountToSwap}(

amountOutMin,

path,

to,

block.timestamp

);

// Transfer Fees to developerWallet

payable(developerWallet).transfer(devFeeAmount);

// Burn the burn fee

_burn(address(this), burnFeeAmount);

}
```

The problem that arises here is that even with a wallet size of more than 3%, the swap is executed. Is there any way to make this swap only conditional?